# Use cornerRadius or cornered transparent image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, quartz-graphics

My `UITableView` is going to contain about 7 visible cells at a given time. Each cell is going to have 4 `UIView`s. I want each `UIView` to have a smooth corner. Is it better to use `Quartz` to apply the `cornerRadius` on the `UIView` or to make the `UIView` an `UIImageView` and have a transparent image that has been pre-rendered to have a smooth corner?

Comment: How are you creating that subviews? Are they images or something else? Are they static or dynamic?

Comment: `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so why not just use a `UIImageView` instance with a smooth corner?

Comment: I just want a solid bar of black with smooth corners. Should I draw a solid bar with smooth corners on a transparent image or just use a UIView with a black background and apply a corner radius on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be using an animations I would stay around from using Quartz. Unless you rasterize the layer the animations will be choppy. Using a UIImageView would be the way to go if you are planning on adding custom animations to the table view cells. If you are not using animations then go ahead a use quartz, it is really to change the corner radius, add a drop shadow, etc.